# Set up email account to be receive only, and not able to send

Tags: gmail, email

I am trying to put together an email archive, but have run into a couple of problems. This question is about permissions; I have also posted another question about filtering. I would really appreciate it if anyone can answer either of these; but because there may be interaction between them, I would super appreciate it if anyone can look at both of them.

We are a small group, team members each receive many emails. I want to put together an archive of key emails that everyone has access to.

My current thinking is to set up a new email account, say Archive@gmail.com. Team members would forward key emails to this account, where everyone could read them. I could allow everyone to log on to this account, or better, use gmail’s delegate function so that everyone can access these emails when logged into their own gmail account.

The problem is that several team members are not very email savvy. It would only be a matter of time before someone accidentally sent out emails from this account. This would look bad to the people that we support, but it would also flood the archive with all sorts of emails, negating the idea that it only contains key emails. I would like to restrict the account, or the delegated accounts, to be receive only and not able to send anything. Is there some way to achieve this?

I have seen suggestions to dummy out the SMTP server, but this is not practical as people use different computers (e.g. Macs and PCs) and different email systems (e.g. Apple Mail, Outlook, and web-based email using gmail.com).

It doesn’t have to be gmail, I would be happy to use a different email provider if it provides the functionality that I need. I may even consider a paid service so long as it was very moderately priced, as we don’t have a budget for this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Bot: it's fairly specific already. How can I have a receive-only email account?